# How to send json parsed data as a response to another rest call

Tags: java, json, rest

I am having a code where I have created a object from a payload by using objectMapper like below.

```
 Test notification =
                    objectMapper.readValue((byte[]) payload, Test.class);
```

Test Class looks like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
public class Test {
  private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  @JsonProperty("eid")
  String id;

  @JsonProperty("st")
  String type;
}
```

Now I need to send this test object as response to another Rest Call.
When I used the same Test Object as response from the server , everything is received as empty in the client.
But if I send response with different Object and with same fields, it is received perfectly.
Why I am not able to use Test object as response?
Is there any way I can use this as a response without creating  a new object